# QnA maker And Dialogflow Knowledge Base

Tags: azure, botframework, dialogflow-es, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I have QnA Maker and Dialogflow knowledge base. I am trying to develop a faq bot. I need to know which is better to use the Dialogflow knowledge base or QnA Maker. Can some one tell me which is better?

Comment: Tough it depends on your scenario that what kind of `FAQ` bot you are developing. Anyway, `QNA maker` is easy to manage and can be develop faster.

Answer (score -1):

Those two options are highly acceptable. As QnA is some easier method. While we need to accept in some cases like even QnA maker is created with Knowledge base. The best solution can be using Knowledge base to create FAQ bot.

Refer the links to create knowledge base and FAQ bot.

1. To create knowledge base, refer the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/create-publish-knowledge-base

2. To create Bot, using the below link. But need to complete the procedure of link 1
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/create-faq-bot-with-azure-bot-service

Comment: fyi the OP's question is off-topic (it's opinion-soliciting) - not something that can be answered objectively. Also, your answer is a pair of links, and link-only answers are not considered valid answers. Please refrain from posting links-as-answers.